# How do i use LinqToExcel to get cell values contained in the excel file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, linq-to-excel

I am using this code to retrieve the receipient name and receipient number but the recpt.receipient_name and recpt.receipient_number are null.

The excel table is of this format

Name       Number

andrew    1223

james     12223

dave      454545

```
//select names from the excel file with specified sheet name
var receipients = from n in messages.Worksheet<BulkSmsModel>(sheetName)
                  select n;

foreach (var recpt in receipients)
{
    BulkSms newRecpt = new BulkSms();

    if (recpt.receipient_number.Equals("") == true || recpt.receipient_number == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    newRecpt.receipient_name = recpt.receipient_name;
    newRecpt.receipient_number = Int32.Parse(recpt.receipient_number.ToString());

    IBsmsRepo.insertReceipient(newRecpt);
    IBsmsRepo.save();
}
```

Comment: You haven't given us any idea what is in the spreadsheet so maybe there is not data for that particular row for those columns

Comment: there is data in the spreadsheet. it contains two named headers(name and number) and under these are various names and corresponding numbers

Comment: So how many items in recipients and if there are more than one then are the properties null in all of them?

Comment: yes the properties are null in all of the 10 rows in the recipient

Comment: @plasteezy: could you please add a picture to your question with the way the sheet is structured? and also show us code for BulkSmsModel and BulkSms

Comment: @ravan panda...i have updated the question. i dont have enough points to upload an image so the edit portrays the excel sheet i have

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found a way to get the value from excel file with LinqToExcel and get the list of all Cells. Check this MVC C# Sample.

```
using LinqToExcel;
using Syncfusion.Olap.Reports;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YourProject.Controllers
{
    public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Default1
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public dynamic UploadExcel(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
        {
            string PathToyurDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"].ToString();//This can be  in Anywhere, but you have to create a variable in WebConfig AppSettings like this  <add key="Path" value="~/Doc/"/> This directory in my case is inside App whereI upload the files here, and  I Delete it  after use it ; 
           if (FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                            || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                            || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12"
                            )
            {
                string filename = FileUpload.FileName;
                string PathToExcelFile = Server.MapPath(PathToyurDirectory + filename);
                //   string targetpath = ;
                FileUpload.SaveAs(PathToyurDirectory);
                var connectionString = string.Empty;
                string sheetName = string.Empty;
                yourmodel db = new yourmodel();
                Employee Employee = New Employee(); //This is your class no matter What. 
                try
                {

                    if (filename.EndsWith(".xls") || filename.EndsWith(".csv") || filename.EndsWith(".xlsx") || filename.EndsWith(".xlsb"))
                    {

                        connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", PathToExcelFile);
                        sheetName = GetTableName(connectionString);
                    }
                    var ExcelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(PathToExcelFile);
                    var Data = ExcelFile.Worksheet(sheetName).ToList();

                    foreach (var item in Data)
                    {
                        //if yout excel file does not meet the class estructure.
                        Employee = new Employee
                        {

                            Name = item[1].ToString(),
                            LastName = item[2].ToString(),
                            Address = item[3].ToString(),
                            Phone = item[4].ToString(),
                            CelPghone = item[5].ToString()
                        };
                         db.Employee.Add(Employee);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }

            }

            return View();
        }

        private string GetTableName(string connectionString)
        {
            //  You can return all Sheets for a Dropdown if you want to, for me, I just want the first one; 
            OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            oledbconn.Open();
            // Get the data table containg the schema guid.
            var dt = oledbconn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            var sheet = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Replace("$", string.Empty);
            oledbconn.Close();
            return sheet;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the property names on the BulkSmsModel class do not correlate directly to the column names in the spreadsheet, you will need to map the property names to the column names.

Assuming messages is the ExcelQueryFactory object, this would be the code.

```
var messages = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
messages.AddMapping<BulkSmsModel>(x => x.receipient_name, "Name");
messages.AddMapping<BulkSmsModel>(x => x.receipient_number, "Number");

var receipients = from n in messages.Worksheet<BulkSmsModel>(sheetName)
                  select n;
```